# AUI Autocompletelist cache issue

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme, liferay-ide, liferay-aui

Iam using this script show list of address using the autocomplete list.Everything seems to be working fine. My address table has only 3 entries but it shows some previous values .How to get rid of this problem:

```
<aui:script>
AUI().use('autocomplete-list', 'aui-base', 'aui-io-request', 'autocomplete-filters', 'autocomplete-highlighters', function(A) {
A.io.request('<%=getAddress%>', {
    dataType: 'json',
    method: 'GET',
    on: {
        success: function() {
            continents = this.get('responseData');

            A.one('#<portlet:namespace/>addressNumberTosave').val(continents[0].addressNumber);

            A.one('#<portlet:namespace/>addressAutocomplete').val(continents[0].address);
            var address_ac = new A.AutoCompleteList({
                allowBrowserAutocomplete: 'false',
                enableCache: 'false',
                activateFirstItem: 'true',
                inputNode: '#<portlet:namespace/>addressAutocomplete',
                resultTextLocator: 'address',
                resultHighlighter: ['phraseMatch'],
                resultFilters: ['phraseMatch'],
                render: 'true',
                source: this.get('responseData'),
            });
            address_ac.on('select', function(e) {
                var selected_node = e.itemNode,
                    selected_data = e.result;

                A.one('#<portlet:namespace/>addressNumberTosave').val(e.result.raw.addressNumber);

            });
        }
    }
});
});
</aui:script>
```

I have tried      allowBrowserAutocomplete: 'false', enableCache:'false' properties but that didnot work.How to solve this problem any idea?

Comment: Is your <%=getAddress%> returning updated list?

Comment: yes address list is correct

Comment: Can you show what data is in your database and how it is appearing in auto-complete?

Comment: allowBrowserAutocomplete: false, 
     enableCache:false 
I had to remove those quotes

Comment: Did it fix your problem? I found a very well explained example: http://marconapolitano.it/en/liferay/47-how-to-manage-autocomplete-on-liferay-6-2.html

Comment: Yes mate. The same link helped me

Comment: Good! Yeah, I too found it very useful. Happy Coding...

Answer (score 0):

You have to use reset method to getting updated address list

http://alloyui.com/versions/1.5.x/api/classes/Plugin.AutoComplete.html#method_reset